# jQuery autocomplete detect empty input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery autocomplete and am running into an issue where it is not detecting it is empty.

```
$("#autocomplete").on("autocompleteopen", function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      console.log("I am empty");
    } else {
      console.log("I am not empty");
    }
```

The input starts out as empty, and if I type the letter `t` I see `I am not empty` printed to the console. If I remove the `t` from the input I see nothing printed to the console.

If I type `test` and backspace the last `t` I see I am not empty. So it is not a problem with the `autocompleteopen` event listener. Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: The event `autocompleteopen` is likely not fired when the `t` is deleted. Consider using a keyboard event?

Answer (score 1):

For all you future Googlers, the issue was within my autocomplete object. In order to detect a length of zero, you have to set the `minLength` attribute to zero. See example below.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    ...
})
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength